# How do I switch from react-native-fbsdk to using an in-app browser for Facebook authentication

Tags: react-native

I'm fairly new to React-Native so excuse me if I'm not seeing something fairly obvious.

Currently, I have `react-native-fbsdk` set up for Facebook authentication. It seems to open up a modal from the screen that triggers the login. I'd like to switch to using an in-app browser.

The code at the moment looks something like this:

```
import { AccessToken, LoginManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk'
// ...

export const actions = {
  loginWithFacebook: (): Thunk<Action> => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FACEBOOK })

    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      LoginManager.setLoginBehavior('web')
    }

    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email'])
      .then(() => AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken())
      .then(facebookResponse => {
        if (facebookResponse) {
          const accessToken = facebookResponse.accessToken.toString()
```

**Question:** How do I get the access token using an in-app browser method? Something like `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-inappbrowser-reborn` would work for an in-app browser.